# create checksum of all files under src

Tags: java, maven, checksum

I'm using below configuration in my project's pom.xml file.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.nicoulaj.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>checksum-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>checksum-maven-plugin-files</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>files</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <fileSets>
                    <fileSet>
                        <directory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileSet>
                </fileSets>
                <algorithms>
                    <algorithm>SHA-1</algorithm>
                </algorithms>
                <csvSummary>true</csvSummary>
                <csvSummaryFile>artifacts-checksums.csv</csvSummaryFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I expect a dependencies-checksums.csv file somewhere in my project but after running `mvn clean install` command, I cannot get any file produced even though the command finishes successfully.

Additionally, I've tried to run `mvn net.nicoulaj.maven.plugins:checksum-maven-plugin:1.10:files -DfileSets=['someClassPath']` command but I got `The parameters 'fileSets' for goal net.nicoulaj.maven.plugins:checksum-maven-plugin:1.10:files are missing or invalid` message with failure result. I couldn't find any correct usage of this command with fileSets parameter. So, I couldn't run that command to get a result.

I don't understand whether I misinterpreting the whole logic. Do I need to change a parameter in this configuration or run with another command to get a correct result of this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your need to change your include attribute to:

```
<includes>
   <include>**/*.java</include>
</includes>
```

With this configuration the plugin will generate a sha1 file for every file. You can prevent this adding this attribute under the plugin configuration tag:

```
<individualFiles>false</individualFiles>
```

[image]

> #File,SHA-1 App.java,b0a90b4032c3fac0fda478551c2217f18b9f0452 Bottle.java,aa70994f30105c0dfc9276c2340e15c9f80be170
> BottleDao.java,23c7c76d5dcdd24fe159ed738f05cf0be607e94a
> BottleService.java,a1a3845b5a1be4031f63837c005f9b0bb4f7177f

You can run this specific plugin from command line with -f option (you need to correct pom.xml first):

```
mvn net.nicoulaj.maven.plugins:checksum-maven-plugin:1.10:files -f "path_to_pom.xml"
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for response. I still get below error when I try to run the command line you provide -> "The parameters 'fileSets' for goal net.nicoulaj.maven.plugins:checksum-maven-plugin:1.10:files are missing or invalid". Besides, I changed the includes part as you wrote but still, I couldn't see any change.